# All Possible Solution to Sudoku Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, sudoku

I'm a newbie in Prolog and I was looking at the example that the SWI Prolog page gives to solve Sudoku. Is there a way to make it return all possible sudoku solutions? And if so, how would it be? Here the code:

```
sudoku(Rows) :-
        length(Rows, 9), maplist(same_length(Rows), Rows),
        append(Rows, Vs), Vs ins 1..9,
        maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
        transpose(Rows, Columns),
        maplist(all_distinct, Columns),
        Rows = [As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es,Fs,Gs,Hs,Is],
        blocks(As, Bs, Cs),
        blocks(Ds, Es, Fs),
        blocks(Gs, Hs, Is).

blocks([], [], []).
blocks([N1,N2,N3|Ns1], [N4,N5,N6|Ns2], [N7,N8,N9|Ns3]) :-
        all_distinct([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9]),
        blocks(Ns1, Ns2, Ns3).
```

To be honest, I don't know how to modify the function and test it.

Update:

I tried:

```
print_lists([]).
print_lists([H|T]) :-
    print_list(H),
    nl,
    print_lists(T).

print_list([]).
print_list([H|[]]) :-
    writef('%w', [H]).
print_list([H|T]) :-
    writef('%w ', [H]),
    print_list(T).

print_all_solutions([]).
print_all_solutions([H|T]) :-
    write('Solution:'),
    nl,
    print_lists(H),
    nl,
    print_all_solutions(T).

example :- 
    Board = [[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
             [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
    
    % All possible solutions
    findall(Board, sudoku(Board), Solutions),
    print_all_solutions(Solutions).
```

But im getting:
_18148 _18222 _18296 _22562 _22482 _22402 _22712 _22786 _22860
_18370 _18444 _18518 _22322 _22242 _22162 _22934 _23008 _23082
_18592 _18666 _18740 _21928 _22002 _22076 _23156 _23230 _23304
_19516 _19436 _18882 _21810 _21730 _21650 _24080 _24000 _23446
_18956 _19030 _19104 _21570 _21490 _21410 _23520 _23594 _23668
_19178 _19252 _19326 _21176 _21250 _21324 _23742 _23816 _23890
_19628 _19702 _19776 _21064 _20984 _20904 _24192 _24266 _24340
_19850 _19924 _19998 _20824 _20744 _20664 _24414 _24488 _24562
_20072 _20146 _20220 _20430 _20504 _20578 _24636 _24710 _24784

Comment: Try with findall/3.

Comment: Thanks @damianodamiano ! I tried findall but im getting something wrong (i edit the post with full code). I don't know if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: It looks like what you are getting is a list(?) of unbound variables as the solutions to your query.  Does the original query (before involving `findall`) return bound solutions?

Comment: Use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clpfd%3Alabel/1 at the end.

Comment: As a general remark, avoid manual writing. Instead just use the top level for printing answers. There, you would have seen all the constraints attached.